# Graphviz same level Vertical Ordering

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have a dot graph with many branches. Not sure how to keep the output as the same order while inputing in the script.

Here is my codes,

```
digraph {

 "/home2/groups/" -> Data;
 CL[label="CL(9+12)"];
 CA[label="CA(14+5)"]
 Data -> CL;
 Data -> CA;
 CL -> Cl_batch1;
 CL -> Cl_batch2;
 CA -> CA_batch1;
 CA -> CA_batch2;
 CA_batch1 -> {ca_a0 [label="G_pipeline"]};
 CA_batch1 -> {ca_a1[label="Phe"]};
 CA_batch1 -> {ca_a2 [label="QC"]};
 CA_batch2 -> {ca_a0 [label="G_pipeline"]};
 CA_batch2 -> {ca_a1 [label="Phe"]};
 CA_batch2 -> {ca_a2 [label="QC"]};
 Cl_batch1 -> {cl_b0 [label="G_pipeline"]};
 Cl_batch1 -> {cl_b1 [label="Phe"]};
 Cl_batch1 -> {cl_b2 [label="QC"]};
 Cl_batch2 -> {cl_b0 [label="G_pipeline"]};
 Cl_batch2 -> {cl_b1 [label="Phe"]};
 Cl_batch2 -> {cl_b2 [label="QC"]};
 {cl_b3[label="Ge"]};
 cl_b0 -> cl_b3;
 {cl_b4[label="cfv"]}; {cl_b5[label="combined_Gcfv"]}; {cl_b6[label="combined_cfv"]}; {cl_b7[label="vq"]};
 {cl_b8[label="batch"]};
 cl_b3 -> {cl_b4;cl_b5;cl_b6;cl_b7[color=green]};
 {cl_b4;cl_b5;cl_b6;cl_b7} -> cl_b8;
 {cl_b9_data[label="9wL/woL"]};
 {cl_b12_data[label="12wL/woL"]};
 {cl_b21_data[label="21wL/woL"]};
 {cl_b23_data[label="23(+misc)wL/woL"]};
 cl_b8 -> cl_b9_data[label="typeA"];
 cl_b8 -> cl_b12_data[label="typeB"];
 cl_b8 -> cl_b21_data[label="typeA+typeB"];
 cl_b8 -> cl_b23_data[label="typeA+typeB"];

 ### CA_batch1 & CA batch2
 {ca_a3[label="Ge"]};
 ca_a0 -> ca_a3;
 {ca_a4[label="cfv"]}; {ca_a5[label="combined_Gcfv"]}; {ca_a6[label="combined_cfv"]}; {ca_a7[label="vq"]};
 {ca_a8[label="batch"]};
 ca_a3 -> {ca_a4;ca_a5[color=green];ca_a6[color=green];ca_a7[color=green]}
 {ca_a4;ca_a5;ca_a6;ca_a7} -> ca_a8;
 ca_a8 -> {ca_a14_data[label="14wL/woL"]}[label="typeA"];
 ca_a8 -> {ca_a_5_data[label="5wL/woL"]}[label="typeC"];
 ca_a8 -> {ca_a19_data[label="19wL/woL"]}[label="typeA/typeC"];

 }
```

[image]

In this case, How can I order the bottom level ?
You can see that I stated my order in order :

```
 cl_b8 -> cl_b9_data[label="typeA"];
 cl_b8 -> cl_b12_data[label="typeB"];
 cl_b8 -> cl_b21_data[label="typeA+typeB"];
 cl_b8 -> cl_b23_data[label="typeA+typeB"];
```

I would like to have the order from left to right in

```
1) cl_b9_data; 
2) cl_b12_data; 
3) cl_b21_data; 
4) cl_b23_data;
```

Every node needs to have the corresponding arrow. Could anyone please advise ?

Comment: I may not be understanding well but what about the ogther nodes? You are only mentioning four?

Comment: @vaettchen That was the example, the rest of four could be random placed

Answer (score 0):

Simply maintain the order when creating the nodes. Creation happens on the first time a node is named in the source code. Btw braces are not required.

```
[...]
clo_b9_I   [label="9wL"];
clo_b12_I  [label="12wL"];
clo_b21_I  [label="21wL"];
clo_b23_I  [label="23wL"];
clo_b9_woL [label="9woL"];
clo_b12_woL[label="12woL"];
clo_b21_woL[label="21woL"];
clo_b23_woL[label="23woL"];
[...]
```

Comment: it does maintain the same order when branches are not that compicated. If they are too many branches, the order would change.

Comment: there is very little you can do to enforce ordering. under certain conditions you have no influence at all. for standard graphs the order of creation should work. post your failing example.

Comment: I have modified the code. You can see that at the bottom left. The order is different than I stated in my code.

Comment: @user3631848 Here I stand corrected. So far I had similar problems only when using clusters.